# Past simple or present perfect simple?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-perfect

Why did he change his name?
Why has he changed his name?
Why did he change the spelling of his name?
Why has he changed the spelling of his name?

I'm curious whether the present perfect versions are correct or tolerable. It is not impossible to use change with present perfect, e.g. "How to Deal With a Friend Who Has Changed".

Past simple: The change took place in the past and created a new fact (a new name/spelling of that name).

Present perfect simple: The changed name is the valid name from the not specified moment in the past until now. They still have the new/changed name and use it officially.

Comment: The one usage that seems to be the most confusing for non-natives is the use of the present prefect to signal the past in terms of the present when that is all that is intended: signaling the past without saying **when**. This question, by the way, belongs on ELL, not here. :)

Comment: To make it more confusing, in American English, the present perfective simple is frequently replaced with the past simple, which means there may be virtually no difference between the pairs of sentences you provided.

Answer (score 0):

As you state, either the simple past or the present perfect would be acceptable here. The present perfect does suggest that he changed his name *recently,* though, whereas the simple past is less specific.

"Why did he change the spelling of his name" is an odd way of phrasing it. It suggests that *only* the spelling changed, and not (say) the pronunciation, like changing one's name from "Sean" to "Shawn."

Comment: Jason Derulo formerly written  as a French name Desrouleaux.